# Hola busco guia por favor

Tags: php, java, python

antes de nada quiero disculparme. Realmente soy nuevo en muchos sentidos. Debido a la falta de conocimientos no tengo conocimientos de que herramientas utilizar, busco que me guien un poco sobre que lenguage utilizar y que necesito para utilizar dicho lenguage.
Describo que es lo que busco hacer:
Quiero hacer que un programa sencillo, lea la 1° columna de un documento exe, y que tome de cada una de las celdas un dato y lo coloque en un buscador gratuito de una pagina web, y que el resultado arrojado lo coloque en la segunda columna, en la celda continua de la cual tome el 1° dato, y que si el dato es diferente de 0 lo marque con un tipografia diferente o colo en la celda.
Y vuelva a realizar el mismo paso con la segunda celda de la 1° columna, y asi N veces con las siguientes celdas.
Espero se entienda la accion que busco que relice lo que quiero hacer.
Quiero que se entienda que no busco que alguien haga esto por mi, yo quiero hacerlo, pero necesito un poco de guia sobre que lenguaje utilizar con que utilizar este lenguaje. 
Luego buscare tutoriales y ya entonces comenzaria a compartir aca lo que voy haciendo, imagino que comenzare buscando tutoriales de como iniciar lo que busco, pero si alguno comprende un poco la accion que busco hacer, y quisiera compartir conmigo almenos como hago que del exel pase al buscador y vuelta al exe, la verdad que me ayudaria muchisimo, Gracias por cualquier respuesta, y si he cometido alguna falta en este post, les pido disculpas de antemano, y prometo remediarlo.

Comment: Según comprendo lo que quieres hacer, yo lo haría en **python** haciendo uso de **selenium**

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. comenzare a buscar tutoriales, gracias en cuanto comience compartire lo que estoy haciendo

Comment: Busca los cursos en Udemy, tienen los videos para explicarte que te van a enseñar y ahi podes ver que lenguaje podes usar. Pero Java, C#, Python son lenguajes muy potentes y multi plataformas.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: @RamiroBarone Gracias, esto me ayuda mucho porque me da material para leer y donde buscar, que es precisamente lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Buenas tardes, como dije en el post me disculpe de antemano, soy muy nuevo en todo, inclusive en esta comunidad, segun la palabra ......"rodeate de sabios y sabiduria tendras"... no pretendo hacer las cosas diferentes a como estan establecidas en la comunidad, simplemente buscaba ayuda, y 2 lectores leyeron mi pedido de ayuda y aportaron con material e ideas para que yo me ponga a trabajar y estoy muy agradecido por ello. No pretendo para nada ir en contra de las reglas, es solo que no tienen un hilo para quienes como yo necesitan de un guia en algunas cosas.

Comment: @Lucero claro que lo tenemos, es el chat, pero debes ganar cierto grado de reputación en el sitio para poder acceder.